# How to avoid slowdowns when scrolling table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have custom table view cell with images (loaded from app document directory), labels, shadows etc. and when I scroll the table view it causes a lot of lags. How can I avoid these lags? I think it's possible to cache table view cell, or get a picture of the table view cell, but I don't know how to implement this. Please, help me :)

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: I set the data in `if (cell == nil)` block, but slowdowns are still there.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // ...configuring is here...
    }

    return cell;
}
```

P.S. Images in cell are high resolution, but reduced to fit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should load your images in a background thread.  If you're on iOS 4+, you can use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) to load these asynchronously.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSString *imagepath = //get path to image here
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with UITableViewCells. I have already reduced image size according to UIImageView frame and stored in documents directory. When i used your code, there is an increase in performance, but still the scrolling is not smooth. I tried commenting only setimage method and it scrolls fine even if imagewithcontentsoffile exists on the code. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You can always use a placeholder image for your cells that loads the real image only when scrolling has stopped, if you're extremely worried about performance.  Also, here are some great optimizing tips. http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2008/10/01/glassy-scrolling-with-uitableview/ http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2008/10/08/more-glassy-scrolling-with-uitableview/  You can use `SDWebImage` to help you use a placeholder.  Scroll down on this guide here to see an example: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/814_Implementing_Twitter_Search_iOS_App_Using_AFNetworking__UITableView_and_MBProgressHUD.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions.. i had 5 images in each row and that made the issue. when i changed the image format to JPG from PNG for the images, loading was much faster and i used some performance tweaks from your reference.

Comment: Oh yes, several images per row would definitely destroy performance.  Good luck with your app!

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I managed to load my entire facebook friendlist (500+ items) pictures, names, ids etc in custom cells and it doesn't lag at all. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check This out: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

This might help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are loading images from URL thats why you are facing lag in scrolling.. you should use Lazy table images check out this - http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html

have a look into above sample code and post your exp. in comments

**update 1** - try to remove elements from cell one by one.. and check which element is cause this ..

**update 2** - ok.. then you know images are causing issues.. so you need to load them using a thread or you can also use lazy table images concept.. seems image size is quite high.

Comment: No, I load images from app document directory (NSDocumentDirectory)